# I am finding the following link on my mobile past option once I restart or power on, any one knows what is it?

Tags: mobile

I am finding the following link on my mobile past option once I restart or power on, any one knows what is it?

e-zfas5x9ao:apa91bhrmkjzwyvopxax8_ahaqhyimnk53h1vjiba6z91wrxs34z6xz6fc_kgsuh0x6wbpsbvvol_yr2lzrkuvu6iyawl1yveebv7vprpfhxebheldcwpopkdmuz7dfdmat18tzoqjkj

Comment: This doesn't look like a link.

Comment: Try to copy anything else, I check if that one still in past option.